# Как снизить нагрузку на ЦП при использовании анимации на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animation

помогите пожалуйста с такой проблемой.

На сайте есть анимация, она сделана в AE и преобразована плагином `bodymovin` в json файл (+ папка с png).
Подключил на сайт по туториалу, в JS вообще не силен, открываю и вижу нагрузку на ЦП 50-70%.
Файл json весит `800 кб!`, не пойму кто виноват, может я как то не правильно подключил и использую этот скрипт?
Я выложил пример на свой хостинг.
http://animate.d58147.hostru06.fornex.host/

```
bodymovin.loadAnimation({
container: document.getElementById('animate'),
render: 'svg',
loop: true,
autoplay: true,
path: 'js/virtualization.json'});
```

Comment: В принципе, всё что есть в образце, можно сделать простыми анимациями  вращения, scale, translate, opacity, stroke-dasharray в CSS или в SVG, и скрипты не понадобятся. Код будет весить в тысячу раз меньше и соответственно анимации не будут тормозить. Простите, но  Вы задайте себе простой вопрос, вы хотите кого-то удивить сложной, красивой анимацией не понимая азов? Или хотите научиться самому, без фреймворков делать их? Если второе, то выберите отдельный элемент анимаций и штудируйте здесь, на сайте примеры по меткам **css-animation, svg, svg-animation**

Comment: если будет возможность со временем, постараюсь сделать пример отдельных анимаций по мотивам вашего образца

Comment: Уже готовлю примеры. Постараюсь подробно всё объяснить в картинках :) Если Вам не понадобится, то кому-нибудь точно будет полезно

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо вам огромное, хочу конечно по второму пути.Просто такую анимацию сделал дизайнер, руководство утвердило - ок, правда когда увидели нагрузку на ЦП задумались)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT буду разбираться, поэтому если вопросы и появятся, то не скоро)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вряд ли кто-то возьмется разбирать и оптимизировать гигантский код после обработки плагинами, но можно попытаться сделать аналогичную анимацию простыми анимациями CSS и SVG/
Анимировать все элементы, как в примере очень трудоемко, это получится уже работа под заказ, а не ответ,  но некоторые моменты можно показать, как это делается. Остальные анимации автор вопроса, по образцу, может попытаться сделать сам.

### Подготовка растровой картинки к анимации

Это самый трудоемкий и ответственный момент.
Понадобятся некоторые минимальные навыки работы с векторным и растровым редакторами.

**Совсем необязательно** сохранять картинку в векторном редакторе в формате `*.svg`, так как код получается огромным и запутанным, в котором довольно трудно найти фрагменты для анимации.  Можно нарисовать в векторном редакторе и сохранить изображение в формате `*.png`

Получается, что проще взять растровую картинку и дорисовать поверх неё, например линии, которые будут анимироваться.

Ниже показана техника, по шагам, как это делается.

*Ещё преимущества этого метода заключаются в том, что приложение будет адаптивным, верстка не развалится при любом дисплее гаджета и в любой момент можно, что-то поменять.*

### Шаг 1

Берем растровую картинку, я снял скриншот вашей анимации. Размеры картинки составляют
`568 х 532px` Вот эти размеры я добавляю в заготовку svg файла.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="568" height="538" viewBox="0 0 568 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjYfh.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

### Шаг 2

Загружаем этот файл в векторный редактор, например в `Inkscape` и поверх линий, которые будут анимироваться, наносим узловые точки с помощью инструмента `Рисовать кривые Безье`
На рисунке красная стрелка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сохраняем файл в формате `*.svg`

### Шаг 3

Необходимо очистить от служебной информации Inkscape, сохраненный файл.

Я пользуюсь: [**SVG_EDITOR**](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)

У него две вкладки , в общем-то всё интуитивно понятно

**Input | Optimise**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке 5 `path`, которые будем анимировать

```css
.trace{
    fill:none;
    stroke:#917FDE;
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke-dasharray: 5,2;
}
#path5 {
stroke-dasharray:331;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="568" height="538" viewBox="0 0 568 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjYfh.png" width="100%" height="100%" /> 


  <path class="trace" class="path1" d="m353.9 285.2 33.6-19.7M281.7 344.2l0.3 10.9" />
  <path class="trace" class="path2" d="m281.7 344.2 0.3 10.9c0 0 0.1 2.3 0.1 3.6 0 1 0.9 1.1 2.5 2 6.8 3.9 25.2 14 33.7 20.1 0.7 0.5 0.1 7.4 0.3 12 0 1.4-0.3 3.5 0.9 4.3 3.6 2.6 6.3 3.6 10.3 6 8.1 4.8 16.8 9.4 22.9 13.2 4.7 2.9 7.7 4.8 7.7 4.8" />
  <path class="trace" class="path3" d="m156.4 383 19.9-11.4-0.6-14 34.2-20.2-0.3-67.5 4.6-2.8" />
  <path class="trace" class="path4" d="M196.3 275.6 148.5 246.5" />
  <path class="trace" id="path5" d="M414.3 335.1 276.4 414.3c0 0-4.4 2.7-6.8 2.8-2.9 0.2-8.5-2.3-8.5-2.3L127.7 335.1" >
   </path>
</svg>
```

Файл, необходимый для анимации, получен

Comment: еще раз огромное вам спасибо!!! Вы прямо мастер класс преподали, думаю многим пригодится информация которую вы дали. Всего вам самого наилучшего

Answer (score 5):

### Анимация CSS

Анимацию рисование линий будем реализовывать с помощью изменения `stroke-dashoffset` от максимального значения равного длине линии `331px` до нуля. Реализуя тем самым анимацию появления линии от нуля до полной длины линии.

**#1.Рисование линии вперед-назад:**

- Если не нужна анимация вперед назад, уберите `alternate`
- Для анимации без повторений удалите `infinite`

```css
.trace{
    fill:none;
    stroke:#917FDE;
    stroke-width:4;
}
 #path1, #path2, #path3, #path4, #path5 {
stroke-dasharray:331;
stroke-dashoffset:331;
animation: draw 3s linear  infinite alternate ; 
}
@keyframes draw {
100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="568" height="538" viewBox="0 0 568 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Btd.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 


  <path class="trace" id="path1" d="m353.9 285.2 33.6-19.7M281.7 344.2l0.3 10.9" />
  <path class="trace" id="path2" d="m281.7 344.2 0.3 10.9c0 0 0.1 2.3 0.1 3.6 0 1 0.9 1.1 2.5 2 6.8 3.9 25.2 14 33.7 20.1 0.7 0.5 0.1 7.4 0.3 12 0 1.4-0.3 3.5 0.9 4.3 3.6 2.6 6.3 3.6 10.3 6 8.1 4.8 16.8 9.4 22.9 13.2 4.7 2.9 7.7 4.8 7.7 4.8" />
  <path class="trace" id="path3" d="m156.4 383 19.9-11.4-0.6-14 34.2-20.2-0.3-67.5 4.6-2.8" />
  <path class="trace" id="path4" d="M196.3 275.6 148.5 246.5" />
  <path class="trace" id="path5" d="M414.3 335.1 276.4 414.3c0 0-4.4 2.7-6.8 2.8-2.9 0.2-8.5-2.3-8.5-2.3L127.7 335.1" >
    </path>
</svg>
```

**#2. Рисование линии вперед-назад: второй вариант**

Так как длина линий сильно отличается сделаем две анимации: одна для длинной линии

```
#path5 {
stroke-dasharray:331;
stroke-dashoffset:331;
animation: drawLong 1.5s linear 3s   forwards ; 
}
```

Остальные анимация для более коротких линий

```css
.trace{
    fill:none;
    stroke:#917FDE;
    stroke-width:4;
}
 #path1, #path2, #path3, #path4 {
stroke-dasharray:150;
stroke-dashoffset:150;
animation: draw 4s linear  infinite alternate ; 
}
@keyframes draw {
100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
}

#path5 {
stroke-dasharray:331;
stroke-dashoffset:331;
animation: drawLong 1.5s linear 3s   forwards ; 
}
@keyframes drawLong {
100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="568" height="538" viewBox="0 0 568 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Btd.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 


  <path class="trace" id="path1" d="m353.9 285.2 33.6-19.7M281.7 344.2l0.3 10.9" />
  <path class="trace" id="path2" d="m281.7 344.2 0.3 10.9c0 0 0.1 2.3 0.1 3.6 0 1 0.9 1.1 2.5 2 6.8 3.9 25.2 14 33.7 20.1 0.7 0.5 0.1 7.4 0.3 12 0 1.4-0.3 3.5 0.9 4.3 3.6 2.6 6.3 3.6 10.3 6 8.1 4.8 16.8 9.4 22.9 13.2 4.7 2.9 7.7 4.8 7.7 4.8" />
  <path class="trace" id="path3" d="m156.4 383 19.9-11.4-0.6-14 34.2-20.2-0.3-67.5 4.6-2.8" />
  <path class="trace" id="path4" d="M196.3 275.6 148.5 246.5" />
  <path class="trace" id="path5" d="M414.3 335.1 276.4 414.3c0 0-4.4 2.7-6.8 2.8-2.9 0.2-8.5-2.3-8.5-2.3L127.7 335.1" >
   </path>
</svg>
```

Анимацию движения шарика вдоль линии лучше делать в SVG, так как движение элементов вдоль кривой в CSS анимациях поддерживает только `Chrome`

Answer (score 5):

### Анимация SVG

Анимация  SVG имеет намного больше возможностей по сравнению с анимацией CSS.
Её логику и сценарий выполнения легко перенастроить в случае необходимости из-за мощной системы логических цепочек условий запуска. Не нужно высчитывать тайминги, как в CSS Просто задаете разные условия в атрибуте `begin`

**#1. Одновременный запуск анимации всех линий**

у всех одинаковой условие начала анимаций `begin="0s"`

```css
.trace{
    fill:none;
    stroke:#917FDE;
    stroke-width:4;
}
 #path1  {
stroke-dasharray:50;
stroke-dashoffset:50;
}
 #path2  {
stroke-dasharray:121;
stroke-dashoffset:121;
}
 #path3  {
stroke-dasharray:150;
stroke-dashoffset:150;
}
 #path4  {
stroke-dasharray:56;
stroke-dashoffset:56;
}
 #path5  {
stroke-dasharray:331;
stroke-dashoffset:331;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="568" height="538" viewBox="0 0 568 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Btd.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 


  <g id="group">
  <path class="trace" id="path1" d="m353.9 285.2 33.6-19.7M281.7 344.2l0.3 10.9" >
    <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" 
      values="50;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
  
<path class="trace" id="path2" d="m281.7 344.2 0.3 10.9c0 0 0.1 2.3 0.1 3.6 0 1 0.9 1.1 2.5 2 6.8 3.9 25.2 14 33.7 20.1 0.7 0.5 0.1 7.4 0.3 12 0 1.4-0.3 3.5 0.9 4.3 3.6 2.6 6.3 3.6 10.3 6 8.1 4.8 16.8 9.4 22.9 13.2 4.7 2.9 7.7 4.8 7.7 4.8" >
    <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="1"
        values="121;0"  restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
</path>
  <path class="trace" id="path3" d="m156.4 383 19.9-11.4-0.6-14 34.2-20.2-0.3-67.5 4.6-2.8" >
    <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" 
      values="150;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
 
 <path class="trace" id="path4" d="M196.3 275.6 148.5 246.5" >
    <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" 
        values="56;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
  <path class="trace" id="path5" d="M414.3 335.1 276.4 414.3c0 0-4.4 2.7-6.8 2.8-2.9 0.2-8.5-2.3-8.5-2.3L127.7 335.1" >
    <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="5s" repeatCount="1"
        values="331;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
  
  </g>
 
</svg>
```

**#2. Запуск анимаций друг за другом**

- `begin="0s"; begin="1s"; begin="2s"`
- `values="50;0;0;50;50"`  Повторение значений обеспечивает паузы в
  конечных положениях линии.

```css
.trace{
    fill:none;
    stroke:#917FDE;
    stroke-width:4;
}
 #path1  {
stroke-dasharray:50;
stroke-dashoffset:50;
}
 #path2  {
stroke-dasharray:121;
stroke-dashoffset:121;
}
 #path3  {
stroke-dasharray:150;
stroke-dashoffset:150;
}
 #path4  {
stroke-dasharray:56;
stroke-dashoffset:56;
}
 #path5  {
stroke-dasharray:331;
stroke-dashoffset:331;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="568" height="538" viewBox="0 0 568 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Btd.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 


  <g id="group">
  <path class="trace" id="path1" d="m353.9 285.2 33.6-19.7M281.7 344.2l0.3 10.9" >
    <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" 
      values="50;0;0;50;50" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
  
<path class="trace" id="path2" d="m281.7 344.2 0.3 10.9c0 0 0.1 2.3 0.1 3.6 0 1 0.9 1.1 2.5 2 6.8 3.9 25.2 14 33.7 20.1 0.7 0.5 0.1 7.4 0.3 12 0 1.4-0.3 3.5 0.9 4.3 3.6 2.6 6.3 3.6 10.3 6 8.1 4.8 16.8 9.4 22.9 13.2 4.7 2.9 7.7 4.8 7.7 4.8" >
    <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="1s" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"
        values="121;0;0;121;121"  restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
</path>
  <path class="trace" id="path3" d="m156.4 383 19.9-11.4-0.6-14 34.2-20.2-0.3-67.5 4.6-2.8" >
    <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="2s" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" 
      values="150;0;0;150;150" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
 
 <path class="trace" id="path4" d="M196.3 275.6 148.5 246.5" >
    <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="3s" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" 
        values="56;0;0;56;56" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
  <path class="trace" id="path5" d="M414.3 335.1 276.4 414.3c0 0-4.4 2.7-6.8 2.8-2.9 0.2-8.5-2.3-8.5-2.3L127.7 335.1" >
    <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="4s" dur="12s" repeatCount="indefinite"
        values="331;0;0;331;331" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
  
  </g>
 
</svg>
```

**#3 Зацикливание анимаций**

Когда заканчивается последняя анимация, начинается первая анимация и так по кругу

Достигается это логической цепочкой запуска в первой анимации

`begin="0s;an5.end"`

```css
.trace{
    fill:none;
    stroke:#917FDE;
    stroke-width:4;
}
 #path1  {
stroke-dasharray:50;
stroke-dashoffset:50;
}
 #path2  {
stroke-dasharray:121;
stroke-dashoffset:121;
}
 #path3  {
stroke-dasharray:150;
stroke-dashoffset:150;
}
 #path4  {
stroke-dasharray:56;
stroke-dashoffset:56;
}
 #path5  {
stroke-dasharray:331;
stroke-dashoffset:331;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="568" height="538" viewBox="0 0 568 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Btd.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
  <g id="group">
        <!-- Траектория движения растущей линии 1 -->
  <path class="trace" id="path1" d="m353.9 285.2 33.6-19.7M281.7 344.2l0.3 10.9" >
        <!-- Анимация роста линии -->
    <animate id="an1"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s;an5.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" 
      values="50;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
       <!-- Траектория движения растущей линии 2 -->
<path class="trace" id="path2" d="m281.7 344.2 0.3 10.9c0 0 0.1 2.3 0.1 3.6 0 1 0.9 1.1 2.5 2 6.8 3.9 25.2 14 33.7 20.1 0.7 0.5 0.1 7.4 0.3 12 0 1.4-0.3 3.5 0.9 4.3 3.6 2.6 6.3 3.6 10.3 6 8.1 4.8 16.8 9.4 22.9 13.2 4.7 2.9 7.7 4.8 7.7 4.8" >
       <!-- Анимация роста линии 2 -->
    <animate id="an2"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an1.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="1"
        values="121;0"  restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
</path>
  <path class="trace" id="path3" d="m156.4 383 19.9-11.4-0.6-14 34.2-20.2-0.3-67.5 4.6-2.8" >
    <animate  id="an3" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an2.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" 
      values="150;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
 
 <path class="trace" id="path4" d="M196.3 275.6 148.5 246.5" >
    <animate id="an4"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an3.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" 
        values="56;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"  /> 
  </path>
  <path class="trace" id="path5" d="M414.3 335.1 276.4 414.3c0 0-4.4 2.7-6.8 2.8-2.9 0.2-8.5-2.3-8.5-2.3L127.7 335.1" >
    <animate id="an5"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an4.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="1"
        values="331;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
    </g>
 </svg>
```

**#4. Зацикленная анимация + движение шарика вдоль криволинейного пути**

Мы шли от самых простых примеров с постепенным усложнением.
Сейчас добавим ещё движение шарика вдоль пути:

```
<circle class="c1" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" fill="white" >
     <!-- Анимация шарика по траектории -->
  <animateMotion begin="an1.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" >
<!--    Траектория движения --> 
   <mpath xlink:href="#path1" />
  </animateMotion>
</circle>
```

Добавлен фильтр Гаусса для легкого размытия краев шарика

```css
.trace{
    fill:none;
    stroke:#917FDE;
    stroke-width:4;
}
 #path1  {
stroke-dasharray:5,2;
stroke-dashoffset:50;
}
 #path2  {
stroke-dasharray:5,2;
stroke-dashoffset:121;
}
 #path3  {
stroke-dasharray:5,2;
stroke-dashoffset:150;
}
 #path4  {
stroke-dasharray:5,2;
stroke-dashoffset:56;
}
 #path5  {
stroke-dasharray:331;
stroke-dashoffset:331;
}

.c1 {
filter:url(#filterBall);
fill:white;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="568" height="538" viewBox="0 0 568 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  


  <defs>
   <filter id="filterBall" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="160%" height="160%">
     <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
     </filter>
 </defs>  
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Btd.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
  <g id="group"> 
      <!-- Траектория движения шарика 1 -->
  <path class="trace" id="path1" d="m353.9 285.2 33.6-19.7M281.7 344.2l0.3 10.9" >
    <animate id="an1"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" 
      values="50;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
       <!-- Траектория движения шарика 2 -->
<path class="trace" id="path2" d="m281.7 344.2 0.3 10.9c0 0 0.1 2.3 0.1 3.6 0 1 0.9 1.1 2.5 2 6.8 3.9 25.2 14 33.7 20.1 0.7 0.5 0.1 7.4 0.3 12 0 1.4-0.3 3.5 0.9 4.3 3.6 2.6 6.3 3.6 10.3 6 8.1 4.8 16.8 9.4 22.9 13.2 4.7 2.9 7.7 4.8 7.7 4.8" >
    <animate id="an2"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an1.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="1"
        values="121;0"  restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
</path>
  <path class="trace" id="path3" d="m156.4 383 19.9-11.4-0.6-14 34.2-20.2-0.3-67.5 4.6-2.8" >
    <animate  id="an3" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an2.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" 
      values="150;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
 
 <path class="trace" id="path4" d="M196.3 275.6 148.5 246.5" >
    <animate id="an4"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an3.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" 
        values="56;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"  /> 
  </path>
  <path class="trace" id="path5" d="M414.3 335.1 276.4 414.3c0 0-4.4 2.7-6.8 2.8-2.9 0.2-8.5-2.3-8.5-2.3L127.7 335.1" >
    <animate id="an5"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an4.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="1"
        values="331;0" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
 </g> 
<circle class="c1" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" fill="white" >
     <!-- Анимация шарика по траектории -->
  <animateMotion begin="an1.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" >
    <mpath xlink:href="#path1" />
  </animateMotion>
</circle>  

<circle class="c1" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" fill="white" >
  <animateMotion begin="an2.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" >
    <mpath xlink:href="#path2" />
  </animateMotion>
</circle>  

<circle class="c1" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" fill="white" >
  <animateMotion begin="an3.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" >
    <mpath xlink:href="#path3" />
  </animateMotion>
</circle> 

<circle class="c1" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" fill="white" >
  <animateMotion begin="an4.end" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" >
    <mpath xlink:href="#path4" />
  </animateMotion>
</circle>
 
</svg>
```